Effect of sugar on the refractive index of water
I'm investigating the effects of sugar on the refractive index of a water and sugar solution. I'm wondering if the explanation behind why sugar changes the refractive index of water is similar as to why salt changes the refractive index of water.
My understanding is that salt changes the ability of the solution to become polarized when affected by an electric field. Therefore, permittivity increases and the speed of electromagnetic waves changes causing the refractive index to change according to Snell's law.
Does the same apply to a water and sugar solution?

I think that the effect of sugar is much more complicated due to the chirality of sucrsoe molecules, which leads to a different refractive index for the two polarization states of light
